# Error when installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package in Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0

Tags: visual-studio

Please assist, I treid to clean all Nuget cache, however I still get the errors when installing
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.  will appreciated assistance

Tried t clear Nuget Cache and also ckecked that correct framework installed,